# How to override a module in sites/all/modules directory?

Tags: files

Is there an easy way to override a module located in **sites/all/modules** directory? Like placing it's customized version into **modules/** directory or create one under **sites/default/modules**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question here:

> Your installation will choose from the most specific one available
>   (first **/sites/sitename/modules** (sitename typically might be - *default*), then **/sites/all/modules**, then
>   **/modules**).

from [Directory precedence and multi-site considerations](http://drupal.org/node/176046).

Comment: Following along here... it looks like if I wanted to override the css of the toolbar module, I would copy /modules/toolbar/toolbar.css and place it in /sites/modules/toolbar/toolbar.css

I tried this, but it didn't work.  Why not?

Comment: Probably you can't override parts of it, copy over the whole module, alter it (css, js, or anything) and reactivate from backend. That should do.

Comment: Thanks for the guess, but it had no effect.

Comment: I could find no other answer and tried this a couple of more times, and it finally started working. I have no idea what I did wrong the first few times.  Or maybe there was a server caching issue separate from the Drupal cache preventing me from seeing the changes.

Answer (score 1):

To get Drupal to recognize the location of an overridden module, you may need to clear caches or rebuild the system registry.